# how to perform groupby in linq on DataTable inside vb code?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-group

How do I perform group in LINQ inside vb code (dot.net v4.0) with DataTable and sum on the group?

In the sample below I need to add group by `GroupName`, `ProductName` and perform sum on `QTY`. The columns, order and where should remain as in sample, I just need to add the group and sum. The format should remain the same (getting row using e("FieldName")).

```
Dim ordersTable As DataTable = _dsProd.Tables("tblProductSummary")
Dim query =
         (From e In ordersTable
          Where (e("Type").ToString() = "1" Or IsDBNull(e("Type")))
          Order By e("GroupSortOrder") Ascending, e("ProductName")
          Select
            GroupName = e("GroupName"),
            ProductName = e("ProductName"),
            QTY = e("QTY"),
            Type= e("Type")
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim query =
         (From e In ordersTable
          Where (e("Type").ToString() = "1" Or IsDBNull(e("Type")))
          Order By e("GroupSortOrder") Ascending, e("ProductName")
          Group e By Key = New With {
              .ProductName = e("ProductName"),
              .GroupName = e("GroupName")
          } Into Group
          Select New With {
              .ProductName = Key.ProductName,
              .GroupName = Key.GroupName,
              .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(x) x("QTY"))
          })
```

Comment: When i use the code, i get the following error:
<Error 52 Definition of method 'GroupBy' is not accessible in this context. >
the focus is on the word Group in the line:
Group e By Key = New With

Comment: from another post i found the reason is missing
<Imports System.Linq>

Comment: the problem is that the group isn't performed. the outcome contain 2 lines with same ProductName and GroupName (and different QTY). the lines should have been combined and the sum should be combined as well. why the group isn't performed?

Comment: i was trying to add the code which isn't working but unable to do it. i opened seperate issue because i can't insert code inside comment and it's not an answer. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527993/how-to-perform-correctly-groupby-in-linq-on-datatable-inside-vb-code

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I've a similar problem with dynamical grouping using LINQ. Can you please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694680/how-to-use-linq-for-conditional-grouping-and-filtering-on-a-datatable)?