# How to perform correctly "group by" in linq on DataTable inside vb code?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Why isn't the following group by clause working?
The original question was how do I perform group in LINQ inside vb code (dot.net v4.0) with DataTable and sum on the group? This was the sample, but it's not producing the desired output.
It returns 2 lines instead of one line.

```
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("GroupName", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("ProductName", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("QTY", GetType(Integer))

    table.Rows.Add("a", "b", 1)
    table.Rows.Add("a", "b", 1)


    Dim testQuery =
                     (From e In table
                      Group e By Key = New With {
                        .GroupName = e("GroupName"),
                        .ProductName = e("ProductName")
                      } Into Group
                      Select New With {
                        .ProductName = Key.ProductName,
                        .QTY = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x("QTY"))),
                        .GroupName = Key.GroupName
                     })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VB.NET, the syntax for grouping by composite keys is comma-separated keys, not an anonymous type:

```
                 (From e In table
                  Group e By
                    GroupName = e("GroupName"),
                    ProductName = e("ProductName")
                  Into Group
                  Select New With {
                    .ProductName = ProductName,
                    .QTY = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x("QTY"))),
                    .GroupName = GroupName
                 })
```

With your syntax, it just uses the default equality comparer on the anonymous objects, which doesn't compare the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim testQuery =
                 (From e In table
                  Group e By Key = New With {.GroupName = e("GroupName")}.GroupName,
                                   New With {.ProductName = e("ProductName")}.ProductName Into Group
              Select New With {
                .ProductName = ProductName,
                .QTY = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x("QTY"))),
                .GroupName = Key.ToString
             })
```