# Linq first value from grouping - Why is this not working?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, linq

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095094/linq-query-datatable-and-group-by-multiple-columns) about how to get specific data from a datatable using Linq and have come up with a solution I thought could do the trick, but it's not giving me what I expected.

Basically, suppose I have the following data to query:

```
Col_A:     Col_B:     Col_C:    Col_D:    Date1:     Date2:
a1         b1         c1        d1        Dt1_1      Dt2_1
a1         b2         c2        d2        Dt1_1      Dt2_2
a1         b3         c3        d3        Dt1_1      Dt2_3
a1         b4         c4        d4        Dt1_2      Dt2_4
a1         b5         c5        d5        Dt1_2      Dt2_5
```

And, in terms of dates, assume, for example, "_1" < "_2".
So, what I want is, for each value in `Col_A`, to get one row for each `Date1` for the earliest `Date2`.

So, given this data, I'd want to get back:

```
Col_A:     Col_B:     Col_C:    Col_D:    Date1:     Date2:
a1         b1         c1        d1        Dt1_1      Dt2_1
a1         b4         c4        d4        Dt1_2      Dt2_4
```

In other words, since `Date1` changed, we get the data for the earliest `Date2`.
I hope that makes sense.

And I could not use a complex query to get the data due to it being from a very old DB model that doesn't support many modern grouping functions.

So, what I came up with was:

**SQL Query**:

```
SELECT  Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, Date1, Date2
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Col_A, Date1, Date2
```

This gives me the ordered data and I query that into a DataTable in .Net.

Now, I basically want the first record for each value of `Col_A` and `Date1` combination, so I came up with this Linq statement:

```
Dim y As DataTable = (From dr As DataRow In OriginalData
    Group dr By k = New With {.Col_A= dr.Field(Of String)("Col_A"), .Date1 = dr.Field(Of Date)("Date1")} Into grp = Group
    Select grp.First).CopyToDataTable
```

And I thought that would do it, but it returns `y` having the same number of rows as my original DataTable (in other words, it didn't remove all the duplicates).

**As I inspected it closer, it seems that it doesn't do the grouping - It basically sees each row as a new group...***

What am I doing wrong? How can I change this Lync query to give me the correct results?

Also, even though the Linq is written in VB, I'm equally comfortable with C#.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want - first group by `Col_A` and `Date1`, then sort the groups by `Date2` and pick the first item from each group.

```
originalData.GroupBy(row => new { row.Col_A, row.Date1 })
            .Select(group => group.OrderBy(groupRow => groupRow.Date2)
                                  .First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it's not doing the grouping... Any thoughts??

Comment: Are that time stamps exactly the same? Or are they, for example, only on the same date but differ in time of day?

Comment: Yes - I can do something like `?originalData.Rows(1).Item("Date1").Equals(originalData.Rows(2).Item("Date1"))` in the immediate window and it returns `TRUE` - Same for `Col_A`... Am I going to have to create a class and create my own equalitycomparer?? What's going on here??

Comment: This was my stupidity!! - Found the correct solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21528865/1693085.. It has to do with the EqualityComparer and the way I wrote my query....

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
 public class Test
 {
    public DateTime Date1;
    public DateTime Date2;
    public string Col_A;
 }
```

...

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
test.GroupBy(t => t.Col_A).Select(group =>
                          group.OrderBy(e => e.Date2).First())
                          ToList();
```

Comment: He wants the smallest `Date2` so you should sort in ascending order, not descending. Because groups can not be empty I would suggest to use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` because the later implies that under some circumstances there may be an empty group and you may get null references in your result, but this is not the case.

Comment: For whatever reason, it's not doing the grouping... Any thoughts??